In Terraform how to reference resource created via loop over list of objects
I have a list of objects specified in variables.tf as follows:
variable lambda_attributes {
  description = "List of Lambda Objects"
  type = list(object({
    name        = string
    description = string
    runtime     = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name        = "device-update",
      description = "device update function",
      runtime     = "nodejs20.x"
    },
    {
      name        = "location-update ",
      description = "location update function",
      runtime     = "nodejs20.x"
    },
    {
      name        = "ticket-update",
      description = "ticket update Function",
      runtime     = "nodejs20.x"
    }
  ]
}

and I create IAM roles in a loop with this code:
resource "aws_iam_role" "role_for_lambda" {
  for_each = {for i, v in var.lambda_attributes:  i => v}
  name               = "iam_for_lambda_${each.value.name}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

How do I reference the role when I create a Lambda functions in a loop as shown below?
resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambdas" {
  for_each = {for i, v in var.lambda_attributes:  i => v}
  function_name = "${each.value.name}"
  description   = "${each.value.description}"
  role          = ???

Thanks for your assistance.

aws_lambda_function is created with a for_each loop based on a map, so you can access its resources by its key:
aws_iam_role.role_for_lambda[each.key].some_property

Example (not tested):
locals {
  # Use same map in both resources
  attributes_map = { 
    for attribute in var.lambda_attributes : 
    attribute.name => attribute 
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "role_for_lambda" {
  for_each = locals.attributes_map

  name               = "iam_for_lambda_${each.value.name}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_lambdas" {
  for_each = local.attributes_map

  function_name = each.value.name
  description   = each.value.description
  role          = aws_iam_role.role_for_lambda[each.key].arn

  # ....
}

Please note that I've changed the code slightly in order to:

Reduce code duplication by reusing same map in both resources
Use the name property as the map key, as opposed to using the index as in your example. Using indexes can cause some issues so they should be avoided.


Thanks for your answer.  It has solved my issue and I appreciate the comments you added at the end of your code to explain your answer.

@BrianG then consider accepting it as the correct answer. Thanks!
